# How to get fundamental analysis report for Cryptocurrencies similar to what we get for Stock market?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Before I invest in stock market, I take a look at the stock's fundamental numbers.

I like to have a similar approach before my Cryptocurrency investment.

Reading below article I learn that the fundamental analysis in Cryptocurrencies is different and it needs lots of manual work or research:

https://blog.liquid.com/how-to-do-fundamental-analysis-for-cryptocurrency

Is there any resource that provide a concise fundamental analysis result for major Cryptocurrencies - similar to what we have in stock market?

Comment: really, what would be the "fundamental analysis" for a currency?  So, if you trade EURUSD, or whatever .. what is the "fundamental analysis" ?  IDK

Comment: @Fattie Relative strength of economies, trade and investment flows, forecasts of central bank rates and policies, etc.

Comment: @nanoman - hmm, it seems so general; it would be hard to get a figures-list for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Stocks give you a share in a company that you can analyze - companies do thjngs, make money or not, own asset or not, have debt, etc. Those define the basis for a fundamental analysis.

Cryptocurrencies exists only virtual; owning a bitcoin doesn't give you a share of anything. There is no income from cryptocurrencies, they don't own asset, etc.
There is simply nothing to analyze.

The real world value of cryptocurrencies consists solely of the belief of the buyers that it is worth something. How do you analyze beliefs?